# get fileList in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm sure the answer's out there and maybe even here on SO; however, my search abilities are failing me today.

I'm building an application with an upload component; we recently switched from a pure form uploader (file inputs and a submit button) to one that uses the fileList object and some JavaScript. I need to support IE8.

What it boils down to is this:

```
$fileInputs = $('input[type=file]');
$fileInputs.each(function() {
  var listLength = this.files.length; // 1 or 0 in other browsers, undefined in IE8
});
```

If I select the input object (which is marked up like this): `<input type="file"/>`) it has the files property in every other browser but IE8, where it is *undefined*. And yet according to the API, IE has had the object since IE4? Unless I'm reading the API incorrectly?

If it's just a different syntax for IE8, I'm happy to do some feature detection and conditionals in order to grab it, but I just can't figure out how to get the fileList object from an input node in IE8.

Comment: IE didn't get input.files until long after IE8... it simply cannot do the same as real browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, @dandavis. Do I need to implement a fallback for my fallback then? ;) (The best-case is XHR2, the planned fallback is the above method).

Comment: You cannot select multiple files at once in IE9 or older anyway.

Comment: @RayNicholus, there are multiple single-file inputs, no multiple file inputs. When you submit the form, it will send them as a multi-part stream. That's the acceptable limitation for the fallback (the best-case allows drag-and-drop, multiple file input, etc).

Comment: What is your specific question Greg, in light of the fact that IE9 and older do not have a files property on file input elements?

Comment: The question is answered, Ray. "IE9 and older do not have a files property on input elements". If there's another way to get a fileList object, great, but my assumption is that if it's not on the input element, it's not available at all. ;) It's not the "list" that's important, as the list for type=file will only ever be 0 or 1 in length, not "multiple". It's getting the file object from the list that's important.